# you need to enable javascript to run this app || MERN

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, router

Я делаю приложение на React-Redux-Express-MongoDb(NodeJs). У меня есть такая логика на сайте, что создается компонент Post, которому берет из адресной строки число (http://localhost5000/post/:NUMBER) с помощью React-Router и ищет в массиве постов, пост с таким же номером и берет от туда инфу. Так вот, при запуске сайта и подключении MongoDb и данных от туда, у меня выбивает ошибка `you need to enable javascript to run this app`, точнее страница пустая и в html элементе это написанно

Comment: В папке public, файл index.html, в нём есть тег `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>` Если ты не хочешь видеть эту запись, то просто удали его. Но приложение от этого не заработает. От того, что написал логику приложения, непонятно почему не работает React-router, где код?

Comment: @Александр спасибо тебе, добрый человек